# Convert d3 Zoomable Packing from JSON to CSV input

Tags: csv, d3.js

Perspective first - I'm not a programmer, just a noob hack who is trying to make some data look pretty! Please be gentle with me :-)

I have successfully used a few d3 visualisations, but I'm struggling to convert those that use JSON to successfully use CSV. I know that changing the call d3.json ("data.json", function(error,root) to d3.csv("data.csv", function(error,data) will cause the CSV data to be ingested. And I'm happy that I understand the format the CSV needs to be in. However, what is killing me is the changes required to the remainder of the code to use the hierarchy from the CSV in the graph.

The particular code I'm working with is as follows - any help would be appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node:hover {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node--leaf {
  fill: white;
}

.label {
  font: 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff;
}

.label,
.node--root,
.node--leaf {
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = 20,
    diameter = 960;

var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-1, 5])
    .range(["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

var pack = d3.layout.pack()
    .padding(2)
    .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var focus = root,
      nodes = pack.nodes(root),
      view;

  var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
      .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

  var text = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
      .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  var node = svg.selectAll("circle,text");

  d3.select("body")
      .style("background", color(-1))
      .on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

  zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);

  function zoom(d) {
    var focus0 = focus; focus = d;

    var transition = d3.transition()
        .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
        .tween("zoom", function(d) {
          var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin]);
          return function(t) { zoomTo(i(t)); };
        });

    transition.selectAll("text")
      .filter(function(d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
        .each("start", function(d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
        .each("end", function(d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
  }

  function zoomTo(v) {
    var k = diameter / v[2]; view = v;
    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; });
    circle.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * k; });
  }
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");

</script>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle ? It will be more helpful.

Comment: Short answer: give up. JSON allows its objects being nested, and there is no theoretical limit for how deep an object can be nested in a JSON. Your "flare.json" has probably several levels of depth. On the other hand, `d3.csv` creates an array of objects, just 1 level deep. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/5201/using-d3-with-json-and-csv/18426/loading-data-from-csv-files#t=20160916151050171808 . The only possible way I can think of is coding, in the CSV, the depth of each row and its parent, but that's very impractical.

Comment: So, because d3.csv can only create 1 level deep, I should instead focus on converting the CSV style output I have to my own hierarchical JSON?